# JQgrid not working for local data

Tags: ajax, jqgrid, cgi

i am posting the data to cgi script and getting the response in json format. storing into the variable and trying to load it in the jqgrid. but Jqgrid not loading the local data even its showing table. here is the jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blastform").submit(function(){
$('#blast').hide();
$('#blastresults').show();
    $("#datatable").show();
     var thistarget = this.target;
     jQuery.ajax({
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         url: this.action,
         type: this.method,
     dataType: 'html',
         error: function() {
             $(thistarget).html("<span class='error'>Failed to submit form!</span>");
         },
         success: function(res) {
            // $('#blastresults').html(res);

         }
     })
     return false;
    var mydata=[res];
$("#datatable").jqGrid({
    datatype:'local',
    data: mydata,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems : false,
    },
    colNames:['QueryID','SubjectID', 'Identity', 'Align-len', 'Mismatches','Gaps','QStart','QEnd','Suject-start','Subject_end','E.Value','Score'],
    colModel:[ {name:'query',index:'query', width:55},
        {name:'subject',index:'subject', width:90},
        {name:'Identity',index:'Identity', width:100},
        {name:'AlignLen',index:'AlignLen', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'Mismatches',index:'Mismatches', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'Gaps',index:'Gaps', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'Qstart',index:'Qstart', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'Qend',index:'Qend', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'Sstart',index:'Sstart', width:150, sortable:false},
        {name:'Send',index:'Send', width:150, sortable:false},
        {name:'Evalue',index:'Evalue', width:10, sortable:false},
        {name:'Score',index:'Score', width:10, sortable:false}, ],
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[2,3,5,10],
    pager: $('#pager2'),
    sortname: 'QueryID',
    //imgpath: '/var/www/test/images',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    loadonce: true,
    height: '500px',
    width:'1000px',
    altRows: true,
    pgbuttons: true,
    caption: 'Blast Results'
    });
    $("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2', {position: 'right'});
    jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#blastresults',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});




     }
);
```

});

the response from the Ajax call is:

```
[ {"Mismatches":"6","subject":"Ca7","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"17305359","Gaps":"1","AlignLen":"1119","Score":"2113","Identity":"99.37","Evalue":"0.0","Sstart":"17304241","Qstart":"33","Qend":"1150"}, {"Mismatches":"1","subject":"Ca7","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"41349183","Gaps":"0","AlignLen":"26","Score":"44.1","Identity":"96.15","Evalue":"0.032","Sstart":"41349208","Qstart":"614","Qend":"639"}, {"Mismatches":"0","subject":"Ca7","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"22007817","Gaps":"0","AlignLen":"20","Score":"40.1","Identity":"100.00","Evalue":"0.51","Sstart":"22007836","Qstart":"672","Qend":"691"}, {"Mismatches":"2","subject":"C11062332","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"101","Gaps":"0","AlignLen":"29","Score":"42.1","Identity":"93.10","Evalue":"0.13","Sstart":"129","Qstart":"714","Qend":"742"}, {"Mismatches":"2","subject":"Ca5","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"10391193","Gaps":"0","AlignLen":"29","Score":"42.1","Identity":"93.10","Evalue":"0.13","Sstart":"10391165","Qstart":"714","Qend":"742"}, {"Mismatches":"0","subject":"scaffold438","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"55788","Gaps":"0","AlignLen":"20","Score":"40.1","Identity":"100.00","Evalue":"0.51","Sstart":"55769","Qstart":"1175","Qend":"1194"}, {"Mismatches":"0","subject":"scaffold1613","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"56169","Gaps":"0","AlignLen":"20","Score":"40.1","Identity":"100.00","Evalue":"0.51","Sstart":"56188","Qstart":"367","Qend":"386"}]
```

please help me to find the error. thanks in advance.

Comment: Does mydata contain the required data? Did you check with firebug?

Comment: ya i checked in firebug i m getting ajax response. i am storing that into mydata so  that i can load into jqgrid as a local data.

Comment: The ajax response should be {"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["AB-Contig743","Ca7","99.37","1119","6","1","33","1150","17304241","17305359","0.0","2113"]}],"total":1}. Why a null returned?

Answer (score 0):

I f you are using local data, it should be something like this:

```
 var mydata = [ {query:"qry",subject:"foo"........},{query:"qry",subject:"foo"........}  ];//colname,value pairs
```

But currently you have

```
mydata={"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[null,{"id":1,"cell":["AB-Contig743","Ca7","99.37","1119","6","1","33","1150","17304241","17305359","0.0","2113"]}],"total":1}
```

So either you have to reformat the ajax result or directly use the url property of jqgrid to call the method( the one you called in the ajax request) like this:

```
$("#blastform").submit(function(){
$('#blast').hide();
$('#blastresults').show();
    $("#datatable").show();
     var thistarget = this.target;
    $("#datatable").jqGrid({

         url:  $(this).action,


                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'post', //

                    postData: $(this).serialize(),
    colNames:['QueryID','SubjectID', 'Identity', 'Align-len', 'Mismatches','Gaps','QStart','QEnd','Suject-start','Subject_end','E.Value','Score'],
    colModel:[ {name:'query',index:'query', width:55},
        {name:'subject',index:'subject', width:90},
        {name:'Identity',index:'Identity', width:100},
        {name:'AlignLen',index:'AlignLen', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'Mismatches',index:'Mismatches', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'Gaps',index:'Gaps', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'Qstart',index:'Qstart', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'Qend',index:'Qend', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'Sstart',index:'Sstart', width:150, sortable:false},
        {name:'Send',index:'Send', width:150, sortable:false},
        {name:'Evalue',index:'Evalue', width:10, sortable:false},
        {name:'Score',index:'Score', width:10, sortable:false}, ],
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[2,3,5,10],
    pager: $('#pager2'), 


......................
```

Comment: Thanku for the response. . . i tried this method i am getting response in separate tab like this:                               {"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[null,{"id":1,"cell":["AB-Contig743","Ca7","99.37","1119","6","1","33","1150","17304241","17305359","0.0","2113"]}],"total":1}

Comment: What do you mean by separate tab?

Comment: means results not displaying in the datatable. instead it displays in other tab in the firfox.

Comment: Did you try the method mentioned in first part of my answer?

Comment: The response from the Ajax call is in same format which i pasted. cgi script encode output in json format like that. i am trying to use the same output as local variable.

Comment: My cgi script printing header followed by json format response. do you think presence of header in the response is thereason for this?

Comment: What do you mean by header?

Comment: print  "Content-Type: application/json\n\n";

Comment: Can you try setting some static data like this `var mydata = [ {query:"qry",subject:"foo"........},{query:"qry",subject:"foo"........}  ];//colname,value pairs` and check whether grid is shown correctly?

Comment: showing blank rows in jqgrid. in pager it showing view 1 1 of 1. why this blank rows in jqgrid?

Comment: Probably colmodel, value mismatch. Can you include the value of `mydata` you used in the question?

Comment: i observed for more number of rows also it showing view 1-1of 1. also i used same mydata which i  used in the question. no change in result. displaying  only one blank row

Comment: In your question , `mydata` contains `"page":1,"records":1,..` etc. For local data you dont need those details. Try like this: `{query:"qry",subject:"foo"........},{query:"qry",subject:"foo"........} ];` and add the modified mydata in your question

Comment: ya this is working fine i modified my cgi script for single row var data=[response form ajax call] is working fine but for the mucltiple row var data=[response form ajax call] is not working.    json output for multiple row is   {"Mismatches":"6","subject":"Ca7","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"17305359","Gaps":"1","AlignLen":"1119","Score":"2113","Identity":"99.37","Evalue":"0.0","Sstart":"17304241","Qstart":"33","Qend":"1150"},{"Mismatches":"1","subject":"Ca7","query":"AB-Contig743","Send":"41349183","Gaps":"0"............}]